# How do I stretch the Y axis in chart.js?

Tags: chart.js

I'm looking to product a fairly small-sized comparative line chart where the actual data values aren't significant (the associated data table always accompanies the chart) but the point of the chart is to visually show the daily/weekly trend.

At [full size the graph looks nice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFCnb.png).

But when the [containing div is constrained to shrink the size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFanJ.png), the graph Y-scale shrinks much more in proportion than the X-scale.

What I need instead is [something that looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrJOk.png).

What am I missing?  I can't find any options that affect this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `maintainAspectRatio` option to false in the root of the options object

Comment: Beautiful!

I assumed there had to be *something* that controlled this, just wasn't looking in the right place, or for the right concept.  Thanks!